# R: Creating value of difference from baseline in many groups

Tags: r, dataframe, difference, subtraction, pairwise

I need to do something I think is quite simple, but it's difficult to word the problem, so I haven't manage to google a solution.
I have a dataframe similar to the one below, but much longer. I have many Sites, each with two Treatment groups: control or treatment applied, "a". The number of control and "a" at each site varies and is not always equal.
Within each site, for each value of "a" I want to subtract each control value, and preferably get the mean of those differences (=the sum of the differences divided by number of controls). I want to do this for all the "a" values within the same site, never between sites, and never subtract "a" from "cont". Basically, this will give me the difference that the treatment makes, compared to the baseline which is control.

```
df <- read.table(text = "
Site   Treatment  Value
1      cont          3
1      cont          2
1      cont          8
1      a             20
1      a             0
1      a             1
1      a             1
2      cont          18
2      cont          21
2      cont          60
2      a             3
2      a             4
2      a             40", header = T)
```

This is the calculation that I think needs to happen for each:

```
Site   Treatment  Value  Difference
1      cont          3
1      cont          2
1      cont          8
1      a             20    mean(20-3 + 20-2 + 20-8)
1      a             0     mean(0-3 + 0-2 + 0-8)
1      a             1     mean(1-3 + 1-2 + 1-8)
1      a             1     mean(1-3 + 1-2 + 1-8)
2      cont          18
2      cont          21
2      cont          60
2      a             3     mean(3-18 + 3-21 + 3-60)
2      a             4     mean(4-18 + 4-21 + 4-60)
2      a             40    mean(40-18 + 40-21 + 40-60)
```

This is my desired output (or without "cont" rows altogether):

```
output <- read.table(text = "
Site   Treatment    Value   Difference
1      cont          3       NA
1      cont          2       NA
1      cont          8       NA
1      a             20     15.67
1      a             0      -4.33
1      a             1      -3.33
1      a             1      -3.33
2      cont          18      NA
2      cont          21      NA
2      cont          60      NA
2      a             3      -30
2      a             4      -29
2      a             40     -7", header = T)
```

I easily calculated the difference between each "a" value and the mean of the control values at the same site, using `cast()` but I think that is less precise, so I would like to instead have the mean of each pairwise difference.
I have previously done pairwise comparisons but of euclidian distances using `dist()` but it seems this is quite different. I have searched for a function which creates a matrix with subtraction but without success.

Answer (score 1):

Noticing `mean(20-3 + 20-2 + 20-8)` is equivalent to `20-mean(3+2+8)`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Site) %>%
  mutate(Difference=case_when(Treatment=="cont"~NA_real_,
                              T~ Value-mean(Value[Treatment=="cont"]))) %>%
  ungroup
  
    Site Treatment Value Difference
   <int> <fct>     <int>      <dbl>
 1     1 cont          3      NA   
 2     1 cont          2      NA   
 3     1 cont          8      NA   
 4     1 a            20      15.7 
 5     1 a             0      -4.33
 6     1 a             1      -3.33
 7     1 a             1      -3.33
 8     2 cont         18      NA   
 9     2 cont         21      NA   
10     2 cont         60      NA   
11     2 a             3     -30   
12     2 a             4     -29   
13     2 a            40       7
```